# Check what cookies a site is requesting

Tags: php, cookies

Just a quick question, is there any way to know what cookies a website is requesting when you visit it?

For example if I visit www.some-membership-site.com and it's looking for a "isLoggedIn" cookie, any way to get the name of the cookie (in this case "isLoggedIn).

Thanks!

Comment: Use your browser's settings panel to find the cookies list and search by domain name.

Comment: Beyond that, it is your browser that _sends_ the cookie no matter if it is actually needed by the requested script.  Only the server-side script could determine if it is actually to be used.

Comment: This will be closed as 'not a programming question'. Your browser has this functionality, for chrome there is also a nice plugin called 'Edit this Cookie'.

Comment: Ah, that clears up some confusion, thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it works is not having the site "requesting" the cookie, but the browser automatically returns the cookie that have been set previously by that website

Comment: Cool, will look into "curl-ing" my cookies ;)

Comment: Connecting to the page and seeing what cookies it is trying to set it is only a partial solution - typically session cookies are set only after you login for example.

Comment: I downloaded and am trying to use firebug, using it I can see a bunch of cookies that the site has set, some say "session" some say "http only", is there any easy way to send these and which do I pick?

Comment: the biggest difference is the expiration - see: http://www.allaboutcookies.org/cookies/cookies-the-same.html

Answer (score 1):

Technically no, because the "looking for cookie" part is done server-side.  Cookies are sent with the request, regardless of whether the server wants them or not.

However, if you look at that request data with browser tools, or some other tool, you will see what cookies are being used, and can get a good idea from there as to what is needed.

Comment: Will do, thanks for replying!